# How to use scalar to copy value from one field to another?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have table with `jsonb` column "Details":

```
{"Type": "VIP", "Quantity": 1}
```

I want update column, using query that copies value from `"Type"` field to new one `"Subscription"` and change value "VIP"->2. Exp below:

```
{"Type": 2, "Quantity": 1, "Subscription": "VIP"}
```

I have tried script but received error "Can't extract scalar value"

```
Update "Media" set "Details" = jsonb_set("Details", '{Subscription}'::text[],
            (select res.value from jsonb_array_elements("Details" -> 'Type') as res), true)
```

What is wrong? Please, help to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the concatenation operator:

```sql
update "Media" 
set "Details" = 
    "Details" || 
    jsonb_build_object('Subscription', "Details"->'Type') || 
    '{"Type": 2}';
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1a373dc670692bba16292fc49a7775ba)

According to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

> Concatenating two objects generates an object containing the union of their keys, taking the second object's value when there are duplicate keys.

Thus when you want to modify a value of a key, you can concatenate the key with a new value.

Comment: thanks. Could you also explain how  || '{"Type": 2}' works? || - it's concat operator, so it should add this value/key, but the value changes in the existing object

Comment: See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a newwer Version of postgres `||` is the right tools fo r tha

> ```
> CREATE TABLE "Media" ("Details" jsonb)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO "Media" VALUES('{"Type": "VIP", "Quantity": 1}')
> ```

> ```
> Update "Media" set "Details" = "Details"
> || ('{"Subscription": "' || ("Details"->>'Type')::Text || '"}')::jsonb
> ||'{"Type":2}'::jsonb
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM "Media"
> ```
>
> ```
> | Details                                           |
> | :------------------------------------------------ |
> | {"Type": 2, "Quantity": 1, "Subscription": "VIP"} |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9ec8157486a16a7dd85e0a0a42237d39)*